# How to suppress npm WARN deprecated messages in bash

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm

I have several version of `node.js` installed in Linux Mint 18.0. I manage them using `nvm`. Because of a project dependency, I need to have version 0.10 as the default version (`nvm use 0.10`). As a result of this, every time I start my terminal, I get the following output:

```
npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,
npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm
npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the
npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
```

How do I suppress these messages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can suppress or quieten NPM via an environment variable:

```
npm_config_loglevel=silent npm version
```

This should work in your `.bashrc` (or wherever you invoke `nvm`):

```
npm_config_loglevel=silent nvm use 0.10
```

Or you can set the environment variable globally

```
export npm_config_loglevel=silent
```

Different loglevels can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) - they are:

> "silent", "error", "warn", "http", "info", "verbose", "silly"

Comment: thanks, that worked. Funny thing: `export npm_config_loglevel=silent` works. `export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=silent` doesn't. Normally, I have my env vars upcase. Do you know why it doesn't work with this one?

Comment: @AlexPopov I agree it's not what I'd expect either. Environment variables are case sensitive, so it's a decision by the npm maintainers.

Comment: Adding `npm_config_loglevel=silent nvm use 0.10` to my .bash_profile does NOT work.

Answer (score 6):

You can also add .npmrc file in your project, user directory or globally.
The four relevant files are:

- per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
- per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
- global config file ($PREFIX/etc/npmrc)
- npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)

Example:

```
prefix=~/.npm-global
loglevel=error
```

More information [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this inside your script by removing the event listeners

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.removeAllListeners('warning');

// Do your thang without triggering warnings
```

All credit to Sam Roberts: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32876#issuecomment-616709931

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021:

(My problem was not an `npm WARN deprecated` message but an `npm WARN npm` message, but this still applies)

I use `npm` v8 on Ubuntu, and I also use `nvm` v0.33.11. For personal reasons I have to use `node` 14 instead of the current version, node 16.

My solution to suppress this:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.4.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm cannot make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

In file `$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh`

in line ~ 2155 I change this

```
   NVM_NPM_PREFIX="$(npm config --loglevel=warn get prefix)"
```

to this

```
   NVM_NPM_PREFIX="$(npm config --loglevel=silent get prefix)"
```

In addition (perhaps this is optional), I've also changed `$HOME/.nvm/.npmrc` where I've added this line

```
loglevel=silent
```

as proposed in other answers here in this SO post.